# Material Design Lite + Polymer not working together - It doesn't display anything

Tags: html, css, polymer, web-component, material-design-lite

I am trying to integrate some **Polymer** components I created with **Material Design Lite**. However, they just don't render anything, it's as if material design couldn't work with Polymer components.

These are the steps i follow to create a HTML+Material Design side menu:

**Plain Material Design Lite side Menu**:

```
<div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
    <span class="mdl-layout-title">Menu</span>
    <nav class="mdl-navigation">
        <a href="" class="mdl-navigation__link">Link 1</a>
        <a href="" class="mdl-navigation__link">Link 2</a>
        <a href="" class="mdl-navigation__link">Link 3</a>
        <a href="" class="mdl-navigation__link">Link 4</a>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Now, as a test, I create a **nav-menu.html** Polymer element with some markup:

```
<dom-module id="nav-menu">

  <template>
    <p>I'm a DOM element. This is my local DOM!</p>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "nav-menu"
    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

Then, it's included before the menu and rendered OK:

**HTML**:

```
<nav-menu/>
<div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
...
```

**Rendered code**:

```
<nav-menu>
    <p class="style-scope nav-menu">I'm a DOM element. This is my local DOM!</p>
</nav-menu>
<div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
```

Now, I change the **nav-menu.html** component to include the full menu:

```
<dom-module id="nav-menu">

  <template>
    <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
      <span class="mdl-layout-title">Express</span>
      <nav class="mdl-navigation">
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""> Link 1</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""> Link 2</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""> Link 3</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""> Link 4</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "nav-menu"
    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

and include it in the main page:

```
<nav-menu/>
```

This is the rendered HTML code (seen on chrome developer tools inspect):

```
  <nav-menu>
    <div class="mdl-layout__drawer style-scope nav-menu">
      <span class="mdl-layout-title style-scope nav-menu">Express</span>
      <nav class="mdl-navigation style-scope nav-menu">
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link style-scope nav-menu" href=""> Link 1</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link style-scope nav-menu" href=""> Link 2</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link style-scope nav-menu" href=""> Link 3</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link style-scope nav-menu" href=""> Link 4</a>
    </nav></div>
  </nav-menu>
```

Apparently it's OK, however, the page doesn't show anything, it's just blank.

**UPDATE**: The problem seems to be that the media query style that shows the menu doesn't apply to the new element:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1025px)
.mdl-layout--fixed-drawer>.mdl-layout__drawer {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
}
```

Since the polymer element is nested in a `<nav-menu>` tag, the CSS style isn't applied. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it removing the nested `<div class="mdl-layout__drawer style-scope nav-menu">` from the Polymer component and applying the style directly in the HTML:

**nav-menu.html**:

```
<dom-module id="nav-menu">

  <template>
    <span class="mdl-layout-title">Menu</span>
    <nav class="mdl-navigation">
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""> Link 1</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""> Link 2</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""> Link 3</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""> Link 4</a>
    </nav>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "nav-menu"
    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

**HTML**:

```
<nav-menu class="mdl-layout__drawer"/>
```